# How to generate a WSP without deploying a web part? VS2010 + SP2010

Tags: wspbuilder

I am developing web parts for SP2010 and am now deploying to a new environment. I need to make small modifications and rebuild the WSP. In the past, I have used wspbuilder, but I am having trouble finding this plugin for VS2010.

Is wspbuilder available for VS2010?
Is there an OOTB way through VS2010 to rebuild the WSP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click the Project or solution you should be able to click "Package", which will generate the WSP.